# Custom autoplay progress bar - dynamic width property - doesn't work in chromium

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, html5-audio

I have a custom progress bur for audio play tag which is dynamically changing the width. The width value is calculated on the base of current time and duration.
I can see that the element width property is changing dynamically and progressively it value when the record is playing but the bar doesn't progress. It does progress at ones only when I click on pause. 
It works in Firefox but it doesn't work in chromium.

```
 $('.myProgressBar').css('width', a + '%');
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that chromium doesn't read correctly numbers with too many decimals. To make it work I'm using toFixed() to convert a number into a string, keeping only one decimal (my number now is a string but it doesn't matter).

```
 $('.myProgressBar').css('width', a.toFixed(1); + '%');
```